# How to map the alphabetic match after n positions

Tags: python

I would like to check if there is anyone that can generate a formula that I can match the alphabetic order after 20 positions, for example , "a" matches "u", "b" matches "v", and "k" matches back to "e". which is simply shift 20 positions.

I can easily do this by double the alphabetic string but it definitely can be done in a mathematically. I know for a - f , it is n + 20, and for "f - z" it is n - 6. just wondering if there is any generalised formula for this situation?

Cheers

Comment: There is "ord" to get the Unicode and here also ASCII number of the letter. Subtract the value of "a" to get a zero-based index, then use addition and modulo operator.

Comment: This method also gives you an alphabetic index, so you can search backward in the order. However, it requires a decision of 26 or more. `import string;alphabets = string.ascii_lowercase;alphabets.index('a')`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Python 3 option, using `ord()` and `chr()` to convert individuals characters to/from thier numeric ASCII codes:

```py
inp = "helloworld"
print(inp)
offset = 10
indices = [ord(x) - ord('a') + offset for x in list(inp)]
output = ''.join([chr(97 + (x % 26)) for x in indices])
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
helloworld
rovvygybvn
```

Note that `h` becomes `r` (10 steps forward), while `w` wraps around to `g`.